# Есть ли причастный или деепричастный оборот в данном предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот, причастный-оборот

Семинар проводится конкретно для плательщиков ЕНВД и ПСН, осуществляющих виды деятельности: розничная торговля и услуги общественного питания, имеющих наемников.

Comment: В современном языке *наемник* — военнослужащий наёмного войска или тот, кто за плату готов выполнить какое-либо преступное действие. Устаревшее значение — наёмный работник.

Comment: Непонятно, кто имеет наёмников, — неужели ЕНВД и ПСН?

Comment: "Проводить конкретно" — это скорее из сленга немников.  Для плательщиков ЕНВД и ПСН лучше подобрать другое слово, возможно "специально для плательщиков", или "именно для плательщиков", или "только для плательщиков"

Answer (score 1):

Формально говоря, здесь два причастных оборота: "осуществляющих виды деятельности..." и "имеющих наемников". Но предложение как таковое требует существенной переделки, например:

**Семинар проводится специально для плательщиков ЕНВД и ПСН, осуществляющих деятельность по оказанию услуг общественного питания и розничной торговли и привлекающих наемных работников.**